# How to skip a line with fgetc in C

Tags: c, file, fgetc, line-by-line

I have a do loop that prints out a given text file line by line.
It works great, but I want the program to *not* print an *entire* line if said line starts with a specific character (in this case, `#`).

```
do
{
    c = fgetc(file);
    if (c != compare[0]) //char * compare= "#"
    {
         printf("%c",c);
    }
} while (c != EOF);
fclose(file);
return 0;
```

This code above just prints everything and skips only the `#` character itself.

Comment: Ask yourself - what marks the end of a line? Keep reading and ignoring the character until you see that marker. Alternatively, use [`fgets`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).

Comment: `if( topOfLine && c == '#') while((c = fgetc(file)) != '\n' && c != EOF);`

Comment: Don't use a `do … while` loop; use a `while` loop: `int c; while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) { … }`.